# Flotr2 conflict with latest version of Underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, flotr2

Flotr2 has dependency of underscore and it also ships with older version of underscore(1.1.7) but my project requires latest version of underscore (1.7.0) and both thing conflicts.

Is there any work around? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`Flotr2` by the looks of it only uses a portion of `underscore` (that probably being the reason the dev chose to include it in the source).

Generally speaking javascript is perfectly fine with overwriting global variables. *Meaning **not** that you should make a habit of it, but that it's syntactically legal*. Thus you can simply include the latest `underscore` after you've imported `Flotr2`:

```
<script src="lib/flotr2.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/underscore.min.js"></script>
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dzpezL9/) based off of the Flotr2 docs demonstrating this (console should be printing Underscore's version as 1.7 -- notice that [if you swap the two `<script>` tags it will print 1.1.7](http://jsfiddle.net/6dzpezL9/1/) as `Flotr2`'s import will overwrite the global `_`)

CDN friendly version: http://jsfiddle.net/jfmdz399/ ([/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/jfmdz399/1/))

Comment: There is also a build target without the dependency libs, allowing the developer to include their own: https://github.com/HumbleSoftware/Flotr2/blob/master/flotr2.nolibs.js